# Controller dependency injection from route parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using attribute base routing in an ASP.Net Core 2 application and attempting to inject a parameter into a Controller based on the route.

When I use the example I get an exception with message: "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate (My Controller type)"

```
[Route("api/agencies/{agencyId}/clients")]
public class ClientDataController : Controller
{
    public ClientDataController([FromRoute] string agencyId)
    {

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void SomeAction()
    {
    }

}
```

Are you not able to use the FromRoute attribute in a controller constructor? Do I have something else obviously wrong?

Comment: Can you post your route config file?

Comment: I do not have a route config file. The routing is being handled by the attributes on the controllers and action methods. Which works great until I ran into this...

Comment: Route parameters are not available in the constructor afaik.

Comment: That's correct. You cannot do this. Route params are only available at the action level. Anything passed to the constructor has to be injected and route params cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. At least now I know!

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to insert the value from the class `Route` attribute.
Use property instead of the constructor.

The `Route` attribute can be applied only to class and method.
See the source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/RouteAttribute.cs).
The `FromRoute` can be applied to parameters and properties. See code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/FromRouteAttribute.cs).

Since the `Route` attribute is not applicable to the constructor, the DI will not be able to resolve the parameter and you will get an error.

On the class level, we can use the `FromRoute` on public property to fetch the value from the `Route`.

```
[Route("api/agencies/{agencyId}/clients")]
public class ClientDataController
{
    [FromRoute]
    public string agencyId { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    public string SomeAction()
    {
        return agencyId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FromRoute` only works on action level not on controller level.

One way of getting a route parameter in a constructor is to pass an `IHttpContextAccessor` to the constructor and then use the `GetRouteValue` method on the actual `HttpContext` to get the parameter value

```
[Route("api/agencies/{agencyId}/clients")]
public class ClientDataController : Controller
{
    private readonly agencyId;

    public ClientDataController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        agencyId = (string)httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("agencyId");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void SomeAction()
    {
     //use agencyId here
    }

}
```

Comment: FromRoute does work on controller level just as outlined in the answer by Ripal, just not for the constructor specifically. (Every time a request is made, a new instance of the controller is instantiated, hence why modelbinding does work on controller level.)